# Async await with a forEach loop still running asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

First of all I did read through similar questions, and still cannot see where I'm making my mistake.

Here's my code:

```
async function validateWebsites(website) {
    var result = url.parse(`http://${website}`);
    console.log(result.hostname);
    return await fetch(`http://www.${result.hostname}`)
        .then(() => console.log(true))
        .catch(() => console.log(false));
}
var wrongWebsites = [];

    var wrongWebsites = [];

var i = 0;
websites.forEach(website => {
    i++;
    if (validateWebsites(website) === false
    ) {
        wrongWebsites.push(i);
    }
});

console.log(wrongWebsites);
```

How it works:

The user passes an array of websites, and I want to validate if they're valid websites, not to waste resources and block other errors. Now to the console:

```
digitlead.com
google.com
georgiancollege.ca
youtube.com
    []
true
true
true
true
```

So as you see, it prints out first the websites array, and then the response. So it's still async. How do I make it wait? I changed the loop from a `for` to `forEach` as suggested by many posts, I used the `await` and I am returning a promise. So what else do I have to do?

Edit:

I tried to do this:

```
async function validateWebsites(website) {
    var result = url.parse(`http://${website}`); // TODO figure out if filtering all the subpages is a good idea.
    console.log(result.hostname);
    return await fetch(`http://www.${result.hostname}`)
        .then(()=>console.log(true))
        .catch(()=>console.log(false));
}
```

But it doesn't change anything

I found a function called `readFileSync`. That's more or less what I'm looking for, but with the ability to call a different website.

Comment: Async functions are still .... asynchronous. The syntax is just for show, to make it so you can write the code in a sync way. If you want them to be done 1 at a time you will have to chain the promises returned from the async function.

Comment: `async` function returns a promise - you have to `await` inside the loop itself.

Comment: Ok now I'm really confused. Can you post an example? I'll edit my code to show what I tried now.

Comment: note that `validateWebsites` will always resolve to `undefined` because of `console.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get all valid websites.
Problem with your `validateWebsites` function is that it returns promise wchih is resolving to `undefined` thanks to promise chaining and your loging

Also using `forEach` to filter array is unnesesery.
But if you wanted you could do something like this

```
websites.forEach(async website => {
    i++;
    if (await validateWebsites(website) === false) { // now value is Boolean instead of Promise
        wrongWebsites.push(i);
    }
});
```

Also note that if you use global `i` with asyncronous functions to keep track of index this can lead to many errors.

However I think this soultion should satisfy you

```
async function validateWebsites(website) {
  var result = url.parse(`http://${website}`)
  return fetch(`http://www.${result.hostname}`)
    .then(() => true) // async function returns promise
    .catch(() => false)
}

const websites = ['digitlead.com',
  'google.com',
  'georgiancollege.ca',
  'youtube.com',
  '111.1',
  'foobarbaz']

async function filter(array, func) {
  const tmp = await Promise.all( // waits for all promises to resolve
    array.map(func) // evecutes async function and stores it result in new array then returns array of promises
  ) 
  return array.filter((_, i) => tmp[i]) // removes invalid websites
}

const validWebsites = filter(websites, validateWebsites)

validWebsites.then(console.log)
```

Get the indexes of the non-valid sites

```
async function filter(array, func) {
  const tmp = await Promise.all(array.map(func))
  return tmp
         .map((x, i) => !x && i) // flip true to false and asign index when x is false
         .filter(x => x !== false) // return indexes
}
```

Comment: This code works. I don't fully understand the promise chaining yet. I just have one more question. How would I get the indexes of the non-valid sites?

Comment: There are countles solutions I sugested one in modified answer

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`destoryer`is saying you should do something like this:

```
websites.forEach(async website => {
    i++;
    if (await validateWebsites(website) === false
    ) {
        wrongWebsites.push(i);
    }
});
```

But that alone is problematic because you have wrap your `async` functions in a `try/catch` to handle their errors. So something more like this:

```
websites.forEach(async website => {
    i++;

    try {
      const validSites = await validateWebsites(website); 
      if (validSites === false) {
        wrongWebsites.push(i);
      }
    } catch(e) {
        // handle e
    }
})
```

Comment: Actually he handles errors by using `.catch` in `validateWebsites` thanks  to this `await validateWebsites(website)` will never throw

Comment: @MaciejKozieja the console will throw a warning if you don't use `try/catch` to handle `async/await` errors. Yes, he is handling them in his promise chain, but the `then/catch` only tell the async function how to handle the results. You have to use `try/catch` to tell the async function where to put the error or the error will get swallowed.

Comment: In this case I would agre only if we care about connection errors otherwhise returning bool and swallowing error for me is fine

Comment: `returning bool and swallowing error for me is fine` <-- Lol! What if the service he is fetching is returning 500 errors? @MaciejKozieja

Comment: Then its simple 'nobody cares', goal of `validateWebsites` function is to check if url is valid that means it can be fetched. Since code will run on server side probably (because of `cross-domain-request` in browser won't alow it any way) I supose internet will be provided all the time so evry other error means that it is just not avaliable